# Should I use a composite or single-column index?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, index

I have the following columns in my database table (`Medicines`).

```
ID bigint, 
MedicineName nvarchar(50), 
BrandName nvarchar(50), 
MedicineCode nvarchar(20),
and price,quantity.
```

I am making a stored procedure with this query:

```
create proc searchmedicine
@name nvarchar(50)=null,@brand nvarchar(50)=null, @code nvarchar(20)=null
as
select * from Medicines
where MedicineName= Case WHEN @name IS NOT NULL THEN @name ELSE MedicineName END
AND BrandName=Case WHEN @brand IS NOT NULL THEN @brand ELSE BrandName END
AND MedicineCode=Case WHEN @code IS NOT NULL THEN @code ELSE MedicineCode END
```

Now I am confused which non-clustered index is more suitable to help optimize the query: composite or single column?

Comment: Not related to indexes, but your proc has an issue.  Since none of your input parameters have default values, they can't be null.  That makes your select query overengineered.

Comment: sorry i forgot to write default values. in actual there are default values.

Comment: I would be surprised if there were any indexes that could be used by that stored procedure.

Comment: @Dan the default values just specify what happens if a parameter is not specified. You can still explicitly pass `NULL` even if no defaults are supplied.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `SELECT *` is bad practice especially in a stored procedure.  Even though you have a `WHERE` clause to filter the rows returned, I would explicitly state the columns.

As for indexes you will probably have to do the tuning yourself by looking at the execution plan for each type of index applied.  However I would have a clustered index on `ID` and 1 non clustered index on MedicineName, BrnadName, MedicineCode since it is them 3 columns you are selecting from.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Medicines_MedicineBrands ON Medicines (MedicineName, BrandName, MedicineCode)
```

I'd then personally include the execution plan and see how your stored procedure performs compared to having the following indexes:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Medicines_MedicineCode ON Medicines (MedicineCode)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Medicines_MedicineName ON Medicines (MedicineName)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Medicines_BrandName ON Medicines (BrandName)
```

Comment: thanks for suggestion. i know select * is bad practice but it is my requirement in this query i needed all the columns. i am just confused which index is suitable to make this query work efficiently. and i know execution plan can help me. but i am not familiar with execution plan hope so you can give me more better suggestion/solution.

Comment: @alirazaiftikhar - it would be hard to determine which is best because we do not have your data.  If you cannot provide the data then use the first nonclustered index I have provided and if it is efficient then use that, if not drop the index and split them up into 3 (as I have shown) and see if it is faster.

Comment: @aliraza just because you "need all the columns" doesn't mean you should use `SELECT *`. [Please read this in full](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list).

Comment: okay.then what should i do?

Comment: Name the columns. You can do this just as easily as you named them in the question above.

Comment: @alirazaiftikhar - write out the columns. `SELECT MedicineName, BrandName, MedicineCode`

Comment: @aaron thanks i have read your article it is helpful. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one -

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Medicines
(
      ID BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
    , MedicineName nvarchar(50)
    , BrandName nvarchar(50)
    , MedicineCode nvarchar(20)
    , Price DECIMAL(10,2)
    , Quantity INT
)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ind_Medicines] ON [dbo].[Medicines]
(
    [MedicineName] ASC,
    [BrandName] ASC,
    [MedicineCode] ASC
)
INCLUDE ([Price], [Quantity]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,
  SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
  ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_SearchMedicine
      @name NVARCHAR(50)
    , @brand NVARCHAR(50)
    , @code NVARCHAR(20)

AS BEGIN

    SELECT 
          m.MedicineName
        , m.BrandName
        , m.MedicineCode
        , m.Price
        , m.Quantity
    FROM dbo.Medicines m
    WHERE m.MedicineName = ISNULL(@name, m.MedicineName)
        AND m.BrandName = ISNULL(@brand, m.BrandName)
        AND m.MedicineCode= ISNULL(@code, m.MedicineCode)

END
```

Comment: @devart: seems like you are also suggesting that composite is more better, include column is a good practice or bad?

Comment: I think, if filtration goes on 3 columns - the composite index is  more profitable.

Comment: "include column" - in your case it will be okay.